# Asp.Net web api - How to get all records

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

Im new to .Net Web API.

I want to get all records where CreatedBy = 1 (This is not a primary key).

My model

```
public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UniId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

My get method in Controller

```
public Subject Get(int id)
    {
        IQueryable<Subject> query;
        return query = from Subjects in db.SubjectContext.Where(v => v.CreatedBy == id).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Main issue is your `Get` method in the `Controller` is setup to return a single `Subject` object, not a `List<Subject>`. Your query looks correct.

The main change would need to be as follows

```
public List<Subject> Get(int id)
{
    IQueryable<Subject> query;
    return query = from Subjects in db.SubjectContext.Where(v => v.CreatedBy == id).ToList();
}
```

On a side note, the variable name `id` is ambiguous. Using something like `createdById` will indicate to the casual observer at first glance the `id` variable represents a User who created many `Subjects` rather than the id of a `Subject`.

And, I'd say the same thing for the method name `Get`... Get what? Get is also too close to the C# keyword `get` used within property declarations. It should be more descriptive. Just a few quick notes that don't affect your issue :)

Finally I will note the way you are returning from the function is unorthodox, though technically correct and will compile. You can skip the variable assignment in the return statement or even skip using a variable altogether and just return the `List<Subject>`.. I also added a using statement for a DataContext which is the best practice:

```
public List<Subject> Get(int id)
{
    using(var context = new YourDataContext())
    {
        var queryResult = (from Subjects in db.SubjectContext.Where(v => v.CreatedBy == id)).ToList();
        return queryResult;
    }
}
```

Or without LINQ statements,

```
public List<Subject> Get(int id)
{
    using(var context = new YourDataContext())
    {
        return context.Subjects.Where(v => v.CreatedBy == id)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding variable names, be aware that Web API binds the id variable from the route dictionary, so the name needs to match the route template.

Comment: This works great! Say If I want only a few fields in it .. How can I change it? 
My modified LINQ query - var queryResult = context.SubjectContext
                    .Where(x => x.CreatedBy == CreatedBy)
                    .Select(x => new Subject { x.Id, x.Name });

Comment: @user2412230 you're on the right track. Your code should work, as you're using an anonymous type. You can also define a class that has just the fields you need and instantiate that class in your .Select() call. That makes it easier to pass to other methods, etc., if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Subject Get(int id)
{
    IQueryable<Subject> query;
    return query = from Subjects in db.SubjectContext.Where(x => x.CreatedBy == id).Select(s => new Subject()
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            UniId = s.UniId,
            IsActive = s.IsActive,
            Name s.Name,
            Code = s.Code,
            CreatedBy = s.CreatedBy,
            UpdatedBy = s.UpdatedBy
        }).ToList();
}
```